# app user vs itunes user in In app purchases in ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, itunes-store, auto-renewing

For in-app purchases in iOS is there any limit on number of subscriptions(in same group for same app) that can be made from a single itunes account? If there is more than one subscription how to distinguish them on server side?

Comment: A single iTunes account can only have one active subscription in each subscription group. A user should be able to access their subscription on all of their devices. If you want to link a subscription to a user account on your server you will need to validate the receipt and link the receipt details to a user on your server.

Comment: Thanks, if a app user 1 purchases a subscription and later he cancels it after some renewals and now app user 2 want to purchase a subscription from the same itunes account, so is this possible and if, how should we handle this on server side?